# python readline() implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
f = open('one.txt')
print(f.readline())
print(f.readline())
```

In the above code by calling readlines() two times, the output giving me are first two lines.

My question is, it should return only first line right? I am bit confused on the behavior of readlines().
Need an explanation.

```
Output:-
This file is for testing purposes.

Thank you.
```

Comment: Once you read the first line, the "cursor" moves to the second line. The open file object (`f`, in this case) maintains the cursor from the moment the file is opened

Comment: I tried with read() and it is giving me same result. Showing first two lines. What is difference between read() and readline() then.

Comment: `read` reads the whole file into a string. `readline` stops at newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're calling print twice, it will print out the first line, internal iterator will point to the second line, then the second print will print the second line.

Readlines specifically will return an array containing all results of readline until the EOF for that specific file has been reached.

Comment: It's not about calling print twice, it's about calling readlines twice. That is: "readlines(); print(readlines)" would print the second line still. But yes.

Comment: The  answer is specifically tailored towards the twice executed readline, within the print function. So while you’re correct in the print not causing this, the internal iterable of the reader is incrementing each time the function is called, coincidentally within the print method. Also, I think you mean readline not readlines. Readlines returns an array of readline read lines.

Comment: Yeah, was writing that comment in a bit of a hurry, readline not readlines. Also missed the parens on the second call. Pseudocode something something...